# jQuery calling a method on 2 different events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 events; one for when i click a button and the other for when i press my down arrow.

They are both reffering to the same method. My code for that looks like this:

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
   someMethod();  
});

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 40) {
       someMethod();
       return false;
    }
});
```

Is there a better or shorter way to do this? Also when i want to add another event to it?

Comment: That's the best way of doing it. You could shorten it slightly with `$('.button').click(someMethod);` but that won't work if you have other code attached to the handler.

Comment: Alright, thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can shorten the first one by passing the *handler* reference instead of calling it through anonymous function.

```
$('.button').on('click', someMethod);
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the thing i'm searching for. Because in that click event i have an if statement.

Comment: But that if is not present in OP

Comment: Yeah that's true, because i was trying to make the question as clear as possible. But i can make that same `if` in the method im calling. So your answer is correct :) thanks, accepting it when i can

Answer (score 1):

Make your method as you required 
pass "e" for KeyDown  and not pass "e" for click  and then check e in your function

```
if(typeof e != "undefined" && e.keyCode === 40)
```

I hope you get it

Comment: @Dreiba have you check this?

Comment: Yes i did, so it basicly checks if the event isnt `null` or empty?

Comment: Your requirement is fulfil with this way only, yes check event is defined or not and then do your code